# Markdown: windows path is treated as a link - how to prevent it?

Tags: markdown

I'd like to put the following text in md file:

> 4. Copy machine.config in the folder
>    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config to some other
>    folder

But "Microsoft.NET" is treated as a link:

[image]

And when I copy this path then an extra space is inserted.

Are there any ways to prevent this from happening (without relying on code block)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with Markdown as such, but more the viewer that your are using. It looks like it's parsing the output (again) for anything resembling a URI.

You should enclose the path in backticks ` so the text will be treated as inline code. That will stop the viewers from converting it to a link.

Comment: I tried three different viewers (VS Code, Azure Dev Ops, some online markdown website) and all of them show it as a link. I also need to fix it for two particular viewers (what the rest of my team uses) rather than for myself (I'll remember to delete this extra space myself).

Comment: You could enclose the path in backticks ` so it will be treated as inline code. Maybe that will stop the viewers from converting it to a link.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Can you please edit your answer to provide this as a solution or add another answer and then I'll mark it as answer. Thank you!